# Excel Formula - Get Value From Another Excel Sheet Based on Column in Current Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two sheets in excel, Summary and Data. The data sheet is connecting through SQL Server and Summary sheet is summarising the data in a table.

Summary sheet

```
+------+--------------+
| ID   | Month - Year | 
+------+--------------+
|    1 |              |
|    2 |              |     
|    3 |              |  
|    4 |              |   
|    5 |              |
+------+--------------+
```

Note: I am using a formula to get the distinct IDs from the data sheet. ID column is column A, Month - Year column is column B. ID 1 is in A2 square.

Data sheet

```
+------+--------------+
| ID   | Month - Year | 
+------+--------------+
|    1 |  Oct 2014    |
|    2 |  Dec 2014    |    
|    3 |  Oct 2016    | 
|    4 |  Jan 2016    |  
|    5 |  Nov 2015    |
|    6 |  Jul 2015    |  
|    7 |  Jan 2016    |  
|    8 |  Nov 2015    |
|    7 |  Jan 2016    |  
|    8 |  Nov 2015    |
+------+--------------+
```

Note: ID  1 is in A2 square, Month - Year is in B2 square.

How do I write a formula for the Summary **Month - Year** column to get each month - year (from data sheet) based on the ID column (in the summary sheet)?

Expected Result:

```
+------+--------------+
| ID   | Month - Year | 
+------+--------------+
|    1 |  Oct 2014    |
|    2 |  Dec 2014    |    
|    3 |  Oct 2016    | 
|    4 |  Jan 2016    |  
|    5 |  Nov 2015    |
|    6 |  Jul 2015    |  
|    7 |  Jan 2016    |  
|    8 |  Nov 2015    |
+------+--------------+
```

Equivalent Expected Result in Pivot Table (with rows Month-Year and ID):

```
-Nov 2015
--5
--8
-Jan 2016
--4
--7
-Jul 2015
--6
-Oct 2014
--1
-Dec 2014
--2
-Oct 2016
--3
```

Effort:
=VLOOKUP(A2,Data!$A$2:$A$500,2,FALSE)

Comment: Not clear on your question and what your final results should look like. For example for ID 3 what would you like as a result in your Summary sheet: the first instance "Oct 2016" or all instances concatenated together "Oct 2016; Jul 2015"?

Comment: From your edit does that mean that every single ID on the data sheet has the same "Month - Year" everytime it shows up? If so you can just do a `VLOOKUP` to search for the first appearance of the particular ID and then output the second column.

Comment: You need to show effort.

Comment: ID 3 should have "Oct 2016". I think the pivot table represents the information better. Each Month - Year will have multiple IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Data!$A$2:$B$500,2,FALSE)
```

The formula you tried needs to include both the columns in the table array variable.

Additionally the array must contain the lookup value in the first column of the table array.

I prefer however to use the INDEX MATCH combination, it removes the constraint of the search column being the most right column of the table array. Using the values you gave for your ranges it would be:

```
=INDEX(Data!$B$2:$B$500,MATCH(A2,Data!$A$2:$A$500,0))
```

For more information about VLOOKUP you can get info at:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: Thanks, my problem was the table array I was looking in was similar to A$2:$E$500 which caused problems.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was the table array I was looking in was similar to A$2:$E$500 which caused problems. The problem with this is, if I get 2 month-year for the same ID, I only get one back.